# CryptoPro JCP on JVM 17

Tags: java, cryptography, debian

The instructions for the CryptoPro JCP say that to work with it, installation is not performed, but you need to register the provider in java.security and register the libraries in the classpath. There were no problems with the registration of the provider. Please tell me which and how exactly the CryptoPro JCP libraries should be registered in the classpath?
I tried to include the JCP libraries via the -cp operator, but the .jar file that I need to run with these libraries did not start correctly.

I need to run a .jar file with CryptoPro JCP libraries. I managed to run it:

```
user@Z:/opt/java-csp-5.0.44122-A-1aacf3ef$ sudo java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.base,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web -Xbootclasspath/a:.:./forms_rt.jar:./asn1rt.jar:./ASN1P.jar:./JCP.jar: -jar /home/user/Soft/Crypto-module/crypto-module.jar
```

However, an error was thrown:

```
21-08-2023 13:51:23.252 - WARN [JavaFX-Launcher] {u.CryptoPro.JCP.tools.logger.BasicLogger} : Error creating AlgIdSpec.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.objsys.asn1j.runtime.Asn1OpenType cannot be cast to class en.CryptoPro.JCP.ASN.PKIX1Explicit88._gost2001PubKey_Type (com.objsys.asn1j.runtime.Asn1OpenType and en.CryptoPro.JCP.ASN .PKIX1Explicit88._gost2001PubKey_Type are in unnamed module of loader 'bootstrap')
at en.CryptoPro.JCP.params.AlgIdSpec.<init>(Unknown Source)
at en.CryptoPro.JCP.Key.GostPublicKey.a(Unknown Source)
at en.CryptoPro.JCP.Key.GostKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:351)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.buildX509Key(X509Key.java:224)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:171)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:674)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1793)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:184)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:785)
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:242)
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:390)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:336)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:57)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:49)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:282)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:94)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:314)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSSESSLContext.init(JSSSESSLContext.java:53)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.initialise(JSSEUtil.java:106)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getImplementedProtocols(JSSEUtil.java:73)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:92)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:61)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:56)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:59)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
```

I think that this is due to the lack of some libraries.

Comment: What does ".jar file that I need to run with these libraries did not start correctly" mean? Do you have an error that you can put in the question (hit [edit])? Did you also put in all libs that the provider depends on?